# Спомощью batch убить только те процессы которые в этой же директории

Tags: bat

Делаю батник, но не имею опыта с Batch... За спрос не бьют в нос...

По частям - понятно :

- Убить процессы: `taskkill /f /im "myprog.exe"`
- Узнать директорию процесса: `wmic process where "name='myprog.exe'" get ExecutablePath`
- Узнать директорию батника: `set curdir=%CD%`

А теперь надо убить только те процессы у которых директория совпадает с директорией батника. То есть, надо совместить эти 3 пункта воедино. А дома ждут...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первым этапом нужно найти путь исполнимого файла, поместив в переменную:

```
@for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in ('@wmic process where "name='myprog.exe'" get ExecutablePath /value^|@find/i"\"') do @set fp=%%~dpj
```

Второй этап - сравнение:

```
@if /i "%fp%" == "%~dp0"  @echo Same Folders
```

Ну раз самостоятельно собрать вышесказанное сложно,
то предлагаю вариант с "убивстом" процесса сразу:

```
@set exe=myprog.exe
@SET fp=%~dp0
@SET fp=%fp:\=\\%%exe%
@echo.%fp%
@setlocal
@wmic process where ^( name ^= "%exe%" and ExecutablePath like "%fp%" ^) call terminate
@endlocal
```

Comment: Почти очень помогло, но не понял как сделать kill зная путь => пошел в обход. В любом случае, благодарю.

Comment: сам бы не скоро додумался, надо немного batch для этого знать