# Как закрыть все процессы находящиеся в каталоге?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Как с помощью `.bat` файла закрыть все процессы, запущенные в определенном каталоге и его подкаталогах?

Comment: `taskkill /im процесс.exe` - для отдельного процесса

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill там флаги надо только нужные вам подставить

Comment: @VladSpirin не вижу я что-то параметра для папки... Для имени есть,для пользователя есть, а для пути к программе не вижу...

Comment: *запущенные в определенном каталоге* Что означает эта (странная) фраза? Каталог местоположения исполняемого файла? текущий каталог текущего диска для процесса? что-то ещё?

Comment: @Akina, Каталог местоположения исполняемого файла

Comment: [убить процесс по пути исполнимого файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831928/)